# Custom reporter to generate Junit xml report programmatically after TestNG execution

Tags: java, xml, testng

Need some help in generating junit xml report after TestNG completes execution.

I am invoking TestNG tests programmatically via it's API's hence post execution it does not generate the expected html / junit xml reports that it typically does under the /test-output folder.
I understand I would need to implement IReporter and a listener to kick off the reports in the end of the execution.
But, I am specifically interested to know if i can someway get the Junit xml report that TestNG typically generates and not a complete custom reporter.

I have a JAVA POJO corresponding to this Junit style which i need to send back as a response to a webservice call and needs to be compatible over a CI pipeline

Answer (score 0):

TestNG is generating the JUnit xml without any POJO.

I see 2 solutions for you:

- Parsing the generated junit xml after the TestNG run
- Implementing your own soap reporter (you can inspire yourself with default testng reporters like [JUnitReportReporter](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/blob/master/src/main/java/org/testng/reporters/JUnitReportReporter.java) or [JUnitXMLReporter](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/blob/master/src/main/java/org/testng/reporters/JUnitXMLReporter.java))

Comment: Would you be able to expand on your 2nd point, i think that is exactly what i need but i am unable to figure out how to proceed here. I need a listener within which i need to use JUnitXMLReporter.generateReport() I believe.